# Does an Alloy XML schema exist?

Tags: xml, alloy

Is there a XML schema for XML produced by Alloy?

The XML is very unique, therefore an XML schema would help my colleagues to understand the files.

Answer (score 2):

In one of our projects we had the need to parse Alloy XMI instances into EMF, so we developed an Ecore meta-model/schema that represents them.

I cannot vouch for its correctness, but so far it has been working fine. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/haslab/echo/blob/master/plugins/pt.uminho.haslab.echo/src/pt/uminho/haslab/echo/engine/kodkod/Viewer.ecore).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt a formal schema (e.g., XSD) exists.